# An easy way to set focus to a field in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there an easy way to set focus to a field in Angular, or will I have to write a big `$scope.$watch.$element` script?

This is my page

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.agency" id="agency" aria-invalid="false">
```

This is my controller

```
if (!vm.agency) {
    toaster.error({title: "MISSING AGENCY", body:"You must write the Agency name"});
    vm.agency.focus();
    return;
}
```

Comment: when you want your field to be focused?

Comment: @TejinderSingh the if is in my controller (when user click SAVE) and then it validates different data, shows an toast error and sets focus to the field in the form.  `vm.agency.focus();` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
if (!vm.agency) {
    toaster.error({title: "MISSING AGENCY", body:"You must write the Agency name"});
    angular.element("#agency").focus();
    return;
}
```

Comment: YES!! - Very easy and simple. Thanks Tejinder.  I wonder why all other examples here require you write a long script to do something this simple :-)